# Remove default axis labels in matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

How do I prevent matplotlib from adding default axis labels to my subplot? The simple code below also labels the x and y axes for 0 to 1. This is messing up my plot when I add actual data (the new labels are added according to the data but the 0 to 1 labels are still present).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.show(block=True)
```

The above produces this figure:

[image]

So when I include actual data it looks like this, with just this additional line of code (`final_wavelengths` and `final_stellar` are numpy arrays of equal length):

```
ax1.plot(final_wavelengths, final_stellar, 'b', label='stellar')
```

[image]

How can I remove the unwanted default 0-1 labels?

Comment: Can you show the full code? I.e., when you plot the data.

Comment: @FChm Sure, just added that line.

Comment: `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()` and `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)` are redundant. In total, those two lines create two axes. When plotting to one of them, the other is still seen in the background. Remove e.g. the second line, and you'll be fine.

Comment: It’s because your adding a new axes instance on top of your original axes instance within the same figure. Delete ax1 = plt.add_subplot(111) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to similar issue. for me worked explicit assigning to right axes by using `ax = fig.axes[0]` (I had a list of 2 different axes and needed for work just the first one)